# Wordpress - Custom Taxonomy Pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, taxonomy

I'm using:

- Wordpress 3.4
- WP-PageNavi 2.82

I register custom taxonomy (*catalog*)

```
<?php

add_action('init', 'pca_register_taxonomy', 0);

function pca_register_taxonomy()
{
    register_taxonomy('catalog', null,
       array(
            'label' => __('Catalogs', __),
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Catalogs', __),
                'singular_name' => __('Catalog', __),
                'search_items' => __('Search Catalogs', __),
                'popular_items' => __('Popular Catalogs', __),
                'all_items' => __('All Catalogs', __),
                'parent_item' => __('Parent Catalog', __),
                'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Catalog', __),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Catalog', __),
                'update_item' => __('Update Catalog', __),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Catalog', __),
                'new_item_name' => __('New Catalog Name', __),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate catalogs with commas', __),
                'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add or remove catalogs', __),
                'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from the most used catalogs', __),
                'menu_name' => __('Catalogs', __)
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'catalog',
                'with_front' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true
            ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'manage_terms',
                'edit_terms',
                'delete_terms',
                'assign_terms'
            )
        )
    );
}

?>
```

I register custom post type (*product*)

```
<?php

add_action('init', 'pca_register_post_type');

function pca_register_post_type()
{
    register_post_type('product',
        array(
            'label' => __('Products', __),
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Products', __),
                'singular_name' => __('Product', __),
                'add_new' => __('Add New', __),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Product', __),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Product', __),
                'new_item' => __('New Product', __),
                'all_items' => __('All Products', __),
                'view_item' => __('View Product', __),
                'search_items' => __('Search Products', __),
                'not_found' =>  __('No products found', __),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No products found in Trash', __), 
                'parent_item_colon' => '',
                'menu_name' => __('Products', __)
            ),
            'description' => '',
            'public' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'meta_cap' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'thumbnail',
                'page-attributes',
                'post-formats'
            ),
            'taxonomies' => array('catalog'),
            'has_archive' => false,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'products',
                'with_front' => true,
                'feeds' => false,
                'pages' => true
            ),
            'query_var' => true,
            'can_export' => true
        )
    );
}

?>
```

Then I create a new file for tax -> **taxonomy-catalog.php**

In this file, I query all products (*custom post type*) from specified catalog (*tax*):

```
<?php

$paged = get_query_var('paged');
$paged = ($paged) ? $paged : 1;

$products = new WP_Query(array(
    'catalog' => $catalog_data->slug, // $catalog_data is the current taxonomy (woman)
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged
));

?>

<?php while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post(); ?>
// Show title, content ... everything ok
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $products)); ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Pagination is displayed correctly but when I click on page 2 or over I have a 404 error.

- Works -> mywebsite.com/catalog/woman
- Works not -> mywebsite.com/catalog/woman/page/2

I already refreshed permalinks.

Any idea to fix this ? thanks

Comment: Have you solved your issue or not? if yes please share it. thanks

Answer (score 10):

Put this into your "functions.php" and then regenerate permalinks.
It works to me!

```
function taxonomy_rewrite_fix($wp_rewrite) {
    $r = array();
    foreach($wp_rewrite->rules as $k=>$v){
        $r[$k] = str_replace('catalog=$matches[1]&paged=','catalog=$matches[1]&page=',$v);
    }
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $r;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'taxonomy_rewrite_fix');
```

The key is to replace "paged" to "page" into the rewrite rule for your custom taxonomy.

This is my first contribution here. Hope I help you.

Comment: Daymn, you've saved my DAYS. But let me suggest maybe better solution I came up a little bit latter:

add_action('init', function() {
 add_rewrite_rule( '^catalog/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?catalog=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]', 'top' );
});

Comment: Give him a medal!

Answer (score 4):

Once I have faced problem about this and passed hard times  hrs to hrs by pulling hair. I googled and didn't found any specific solution about the topics. I found several talents' article but they weren't satisfying my problems. Actually custom taxonomy archive page pagination is depends on some settings of arguments of related functions. So I am actually going here sharing my thoughts of  solving the taxonomy archive pagination problem.

Five things you need for custom taxonomy archive page pagination working perfectly :

( 1 ) Don't put `exclude_from_search` parameter key as `register_post_type` argument parameter or
        if mention set it `'exclude_from_search' => false`. By default it is set `false` if not mentioned.

( 2 ) The taxonomy that will be use with the custom post type set
         `'taxonomies' => 'custom_taxonomy_name'` as `register_post_type` argument parameter or
         use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` directly.
         Custom taxonomies still need to be registered with `register_taxonomy()`.

( 3 ) While querying within `new WP_Query ($args)`

```
i ) If not set in admin `static front page` use before `new WP_Query($args)` 

$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 and use $query = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => $paged ) );

ii ) If set in admin static front page use before 'new WP_Query($args)'
  $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
  and use $query = new WP_Query( array( 'page' => $paged ) );
```

Remember to use  `posts_per_page` and `paged` parameter in `new WP_Query($arg)` argument array.
If not set `static front page` then you should use `page` parameter in `new WP_Query ($arg)` argument array

( 4 ) Use Wordpress `paginate_links( $args )` function like the example below to render pagination in archive template file.

```
<?php $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
                  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                  'format' => '?paged=%#%',  or   '/paged=%#%',  // if using pretty permalink
                   'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                   'total' => $query->max_num_pages ) ); // Here $max_num_pages is the properties of  new WP_Query() object . It is total number of pages. Is the result of $found_posts / $posts_per_page
 ?>
```

( 5 ) The `paginate_links()` function output the `ul li` listing with `page-numbers` class.
        If you use bootstrap inject `pagination` class to the `ul` with the help of javascript or jquery and a nice fancy pagination         will be output.

Hope you can now enjoy pagination in the taxonomy archive template without any 404 problem :-)

Comment: I have exact same problem but still getting 404 page.

Answer (score 3):

**What helped me is to set "Blog pages show at most" in Reading Settings to 1. Then it works.**

With the default 10, it throws 404 error on page 2. On page 1 it's all perfect.

So given this works, the solution is to set **"Blog pages show at most"** to 1 only for those taxonomies or categories you need. The code you should place inside **functions.php** is here: https://forums.envato.com/t/wordpress-custom-page-type-taxonomy-pagination/76549/12

Answer (score 0):

Basically that's

```
get_query_var('page')
```

that holds the page number

from the working code:

```
global $query_string;

$page_index = max(1, get_query_var('page'));

parse_str($query_string, $queryParams);
$queryParams['paged'] = $page_index;
$queryParams['posts_per_page'] = $posts_per_page;
query_posts($queryParams);
```

Comment: I just tried with default permalinks and http://website.com/?catalog=woman&page=2 works contrariwise http://website.com/?catalog=woman&paged=2 not

Comment: As far as i know wp-pagenavi is not used well with the recreated WP_Query.
Did you try to use $query_string ?

Answer (score 0):

Use query_posts instead of wp_query. It should work.

This is my Code.

```
  <?php             

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

             $args = array(

            'paged' => $paged,

            'orderby' => 'asc',

                'tax_query' => array(

                    array(

                        'taxonomy' => "$term->taxonomy",

                        'terms' => "$term->name",

                        'field' => 'slug'  

                    )

                )

            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if($query->have_posts() ) :   
// your code
?>  

<?php endwhile; endif; 
             wp_pagenavi();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create any CPT then you need to add this function.

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

It will manage/adjust/reassign your memory.
So please add this line your code will work.
Precaution.

```
1: Add this function : flush_rewrite_rules();
2:Your pagination function (wp_pagenavi()) will call just below the endwhile;
```

I 'm sure,your pagination will work and let me know if it will not work.
Thanking you.