# Error 404 page when i try view my custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, custom-taxonomy

I using custom post type
In the admin interface that displays the number of posts of custom post type by custom taxonomy on but when access (view), the custom taxonomy returns 404. 
Custom post type `oto` 
custom taxonomy `oto-models` 
when I view the `oto-404 models`.

Comment: Hope this can help you...

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31240231/5084291

It works to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you flushed the rewrite rules? otherwise the new taxonomys won't work.

just add `flush_rewrite_rules();` and remove it after one request.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: i cant fix it. because all other taxonomy using normaly. but one.